# Javascript native equivalent to JQuery .each() & $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which looks at each div with class `.comment` and shortens the text if more than 100 characters. Using JQuery.

Question is how to convert to native javascript, I can't find equivalents for `.each()` or `$(this)`

```
var showChar = 100;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "more";
var lesstext = "less";
$('.comment').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `.each()`: `for` loop; `$(this)`: `this`.

Comment: seeing as jQuery is written in javascript, you could look up how they do it, as a note on any other jQuery vs. native JS questions.

Comment: As far as actually getting the elements to perform the for loop on, you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('comment');`

Comment: I agree with @AstroCB that a for loop is basically equivalent to .each(), *but*, since $(this) returns a jQuery object, there really is no non-jQuery equivalent. It is jQuery specific by definition.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're not going to find a native equivalent to `$(this)` because that **is** the jQuery function. There wouldn't be any reason to write the `$` function if it already existed natively.

As for the `.each` part, you can work with any array like this:

```
var $comments = $('.comment');
comments.forEach(function(comment) { ... });
```

or using a simple `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0, len = $comments.length; i < len; i++) {
    var comment = $comments[i];
}
```

If you want to remove jQuery entirely, you'll need to get your elements using `document.getElementsByClassName`. This will return an `HTMLCollection` which does not have the `forEach` function so you'll need to use a `for` loop like above.

Also note that you won't have access to the `.html` function. Instead, you can access and modify it with the `.innerHTML` property of each node.

```
var comments = document.getElementsByClassName('comment');
for (var i = 0, len = comments.length; i < len; i++) {
    var comment = comments[i];
    var content = comment.innerHTML;
    ...
    comment.innerHTML = html;
}
```

### Update: 2019-12-02

Nowadays it is more common to use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for querying elements and you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) if you would like to convert the `NodeList` to an array.

```js
function boldComments() {
  const comments = document.querySelectorAll('.comment');
  comments.forEach(comment => {
    comment.innerHTML = '<b>' + comment.innerHTML + '</b>';
  })
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', boldComments);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="comment">Comment A</li>
  <li class="comment">Comment B</li>
  <li class="comment">Comment C</li>
  <li class="comment">Comment D</li>
</ul>
<button>Bold comments</button>
```

Comment: Just a note: `$('.comments')` should be `document.getElementsByClassName("comment")` since you're going for pure JS here.

Comment: @AstroCB, I couldn't get `document.getElementsByClassName` to work on jsfiddle. Does it work for you? I'm using Chrome btw.

Comment: @Zack It should: that's a standard JS function.

Comment: @AstroCB True. Edited answer to address that.

Comment: OK, nevermind, I figured out my problem was that I didn't wait until the document was loaded, so there were no elements with that class created yet.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` has a gotcha worth being aware of.  The collection it returns is supposed to be live (ie: it updates as the document changes).  This can cause weird-looking  iteration issues if your loop removes the `comment` class from an element, adds it to other elements, or adds elements that have it.  You can get around that by copying the elements into an array before iterating, or by using `document.querySelectorAll('.content')` instead, which returns a non-live list.

Answer (score 4):

See EcmaScript 6 example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.comments').forEach(function (comment) {
     var content = comment.innerHTML

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span></span>';

            comment.innerHTML=html;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually `this` refers to the current context. It is the window object if used  without event listener. If used in oo Javascript `this` is the object's context. So `$(this)` is is the element you are currently listening an event on.
***It is the current context of the element on which event triggers.*** In your case it is an object upon which jQuery.each method is invoked.

### **Implementing jQuery $.each method in Vanilla JavaScript**

You can actually implement jQuery as a whole but it requires knowledge of Core JavaScript. In the case of .each method we are going to prototype Object class.
The simplest `each` method is:

```
 Object.prototype.each = function(callback){
       if(typeof callback !== 'function') throw new Error('Callback should 
                    be a function');
       for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        callback(this[i]);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Look at this now `this` refers to the context of `Object`. By returning `this` you can allow method chaining.
This `each` method gives you the easy way to traverse on DOM. Give it a try. It gives parent + childs of the current parent in callback's first argument.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Javascript (Ecmascript 6) have forEach() included. The current version, Ecmascript 5 has the forEach into arrays. So you can use the forEach into arrays or keep using the jQuery that has it already solved.