# What is the pure javascript equivalent for $('.classname').each(...)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

I am trying to create a form similar to a grading program for school.  As part of the assignment, we are NOT allowed to use jQuery.  I found the exact jQuery function I am wanting, but I am not sure how to convert it into pure javascript.  I can pretty much figure everything out except the $('.grade').each(...) part of it.

HTML

```
<input id="week1" class="grade" name="week1" type="number">
<input id="week2" class="grade" name="week2" type="number">
<input id="week3" class="grade" name="week3" type="number">

<button id="display">Display</button>

<p id="results"></p>
```

Original jQuery

```
$("#display").click(function() {
     var student_grade = new Array();
     $('.grade').each(function() {
          student_grade.push( $(this).val() );
     })
     var filtered = student_grade.filter(function(el) { return el; });
     $('#results').html(filtered);
});
```

My attempt at converting

```
 document.getElementById("display").onclick = function() {
     var student_grade = new Array();

      //here's where I need help converting to JavaScript
     $('.grade').each(function() {
         student_grade.push(this.value );
     })

     var filtered = student_grade.filter(function(el) { return el; });

     document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = filtered;
 };
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Javascript native equivalent to JQuery .each() & $(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247225/javascript-native-equivalent-to-jquery-each-this)

Comment: I don't believe in just giving out a homework answer, but you'll probably find https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName interesting....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> The Document method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) *NodeList* representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

and [**`forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method executes a provided function once for each array element.

```js
document.getElementById('display').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var student_grade = new Array();
  var gradeList = document.querySelectorAll('.grade');
  Array.from(gradeList).forEach(function(el) {
    student_grade.push(el.value);
  });
  var filtered = student_grade.filter(function(el) { return el; });
  document.getElementById('results').textContent = filtered;
});
```

```html
<input id="week1" class="grade" name="week1" type="number">
<input id="week2" class="grade" name="week2" type="number">
<input id="week3" class="grade" name="week3" type="number">

<button id="display">Display</button>

<p id="results"></p>
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Matt, you are most welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.grade').each(function() {
     student_grade.push(this.value );
 })
```

---

```
 document.querySelectorAll("input.grade").forEach(item => {
     student_grade.push(item.value);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`const student_grade = [...document.getElementsByClassName('grade')]`

If you are not aware of the spread operator, `...` you should be.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

https://www.gavsblog.com/blog/htmlcollection-foreach-loop-convert-object-to-array-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This shows how `$(".some-class").each()` is done:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".some-link").forEach((el, i) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", ev => console.log("clicked on", el.innerHTML, i))
);
```

```css
.some-link {
  line-height: 1.25em;
  outline: 1px dotted orange
}
```

```html
<div class="some-link">a</div>
<div class="some-link">b</div>
<div class="some-link">c</div>
<div class="some-link">d</div>
<div class="some-link">e</div>
```

Using for-of loop:

```js
let arr = document.querySelectorAll(".some-link");

for (const el of arr) {
  el.addEventListener("click", ev => console.log("clicked on", el.innerHTML));
}
```

```css
.some-link {
  line-height: 1.25em;
  outline: 1px dotted orange
}
```

```html
<div class="some-link">a</div>
<div class="some-link">b</div>
<div class="some-link">c</div>
<div class="some-link">d</div>
<div class="some-link">e</div>
```